# Exclude Categories from wp_list_categories()

Tags: exclude, categories

in before: I already searched for this answer her but couldn't find a thing that worked for me.

I have a Lot of Categories and Child Categories. I use them to give a Location, Country, Type of Employment, etc to different posts and to later sort them in my sidebar. My code looks like this.

```
        $country_filter = array(
                    "show_count" => 0, // no count behind each Category
                    "hide_empty" => 1, // no empty categories
                    "exclude" => "24", // THE ONE to exclude
                    "child_of" => 55, // category ID
                    "title_li" => "");  // leaves the title empty so we can use the headline above

        wp_list_categories($country_filter);
```

The Thing is: Every post has a Category 55 (it's the Country Category) but can also have 24 - which is a category that should never show up on search, sidebar, etc. this one is only displayed on a specific page.

My question is: How can I remove posts in category 24 from the list? The above snippet doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to exclude the posts of category ID 24 only. right? other categories show their posts.

Comment: Also remove the double quotes from the value of exclude.
use this 24 instead of "24"

Comment: Removing the "" didn't change anything (but you're right they shouldn't be their). I want to remove a post if it has category 24, no matter what else categories it has.

Comment: The code seems correct. Does category 24 come under category 55?

Comment: what do you mean with "under"?

Comment: that cat-ID 24 was a child category of 55?

Comment: Oh no. Category 24 is "Internal" and 55 is Country which holds a list of different Countries (Germany, UK, Netherlands, etc...). It's a Job System based on WordPress and everything under Internal (24) shouldn't show up because it's pending for review OR just for Company Interns to apply.

Comment: Category 24 has no children, only 55 has some.

Comment: then there is no need to use the exclude, with the help of child_of it only shows the posts of that categories those are the child of 55. i guess.

Comment: The problem is:  it shows the Child of 55 even if its also in category 24 - and this shouldn't be, because when someone clicks a link (e.g. Spain) the /category/spain page won't show something if the post with category "Spain" also has Category 24. 

I managed to exclude this category everywhere but only this function totally drives me nuts because it doesn't exclude the posts if they're also inside Category 55. I don't want to tell the Client he has to leave the Country thing empty for his internal Stuff (that ain't no option anyway). Well, thanks for your if I find a way I'll post it here.

Comment: did the post link with two categories 24 and 55?

Comment: Yes it has both of them. And if it has both it should be excluded.

Comment: i think that was the main issue, the post has two categories, that causes the issue when you use the wp_list_categories function. including the same post of cat-55 and exclude the  same post from cat-24.
get my point?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11874/discussion-between-moaz-ateeq-and-kevin-gimbel)

Comment: I think I get it, but shouldn't WordPress be able to handle such stuff? I also found that [there was a bug](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp_list_categories-does-not-accept-exclude-anymore) but it is said to be removed in 3.7.1